# Installshield custom command line

Tags: windows-installation, installshield

I have inherited an Installshield Developer 8.0 project that is configured to install a shortcut of the application to the Desktop. A user of this software would like a command line option added to the Setup.exe to prevent this shortcut. I don't really even know where to begin with adding custom command line options.

I'm using Installshield Developer 8.0, Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a SuperUser question, but if the IS package is built to deploy the shortcut, there's no way to prevent it from the command line. You'll need to edit the package with InstallShield and edit out the shortcut.

Good luck!